# NodeJS Buffer to String errors

Tags: xml, node.js, parsing, buffer

i am using https.req to get some xml files. i get data back after call back i convert that buffer in to string using

```
var data = Chunk.toString("utf-8");
```

And then i am parsing this xml file with objtree or xml2js. 
for a while it was all ok cause files were really small and nothing could go wrong. but now i am parsing a huge xml file and my parses give me errors.

for couple of hours i was thinking parser is just bad. tried many of them. then i decided to use validator to check if smth worng with xml. so i used link for xml document in browser, copied it from browser window and inspected my xml doc. all looked fine. but then i used

```
console.log(data);
```

and it gave me same document but validator threw me tons of errors. so now i am sure i am doing smth wrong with buffer it self. and converting it to string.

errors were unclosed tags, unfinished rows empty attributes and values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

The first is that (assuming `Chunk` is what I think it is) you should not assume all of your data will arrive in a single `'data'` event, so you will need to buffer received chunks and use the buffered data once you see the `'end'` event on the response stream.

Secondly, if you're converting to UTF-8, you will probably want to instead call `response.setEncoding('utf8')`, which will make sure that any multibyte characters that are split across chunks do not get converted to invalid character byte sequences. Once you do this, that means you can just do `buffer += chunk`.

Comment: yeah. just did a test. data didnt come in 1 big chunk:) wasnt aware of that. U SAVED MY DAY!!!!